# Android webview live stream video stop playing after a few minutes

Tags: javascript, android, webview, live

I made an app about live TV stream. It runs well but after a few minutes it auto stops. I click on the screen but it doesn't work. I have already shown my code. If there is anything to add or remove please tell me. I already tried but failed.

```
package ******************************.thelivetv;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    private WebView webView;


    String url2 = "file:///android_asset/error.html";
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        webView = new WebView(this);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(webView);



        final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        if (isOnline(MainActivity.this)) {
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                // autoplay when finished loading via javascript injection
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()");
                }
            });
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            webView.loadUrl("http://shafatillullah.com/blackboy/channel9/");
        } else {
            String message = "Internet connection not available. Try later";
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();


        }



        //full screen ad

        final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();


        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
        // Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.bigscreen));

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Call displayInterstitial() function
                displayInterstitial();

            }
        });
        //end ad view



    }

    //Admob ad load
    public void displayInterstitial() {
        // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }




    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.i("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode);
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

            view.loadUrl(url2);
        }
    }


    // For full screen View
    class FullScreenActivity {
        public void invoke() {
            // remove title
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        webView.onPause();
    }



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        webView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    public static boolean isOnline(Context c) {
        boolean result = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ninfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ninfo != null) {
            result = ninfo.isConnected();
        }

        return result;
    }



}
```

Comment: Note that questions featuring "please help me" and "please edit my code and fix it for me" are usually downvoted heavily here, so when I see one that has +2 on it, my instinct tells me that people known to the OP are upvoting it. If you are aware of anyone doing that, please tell them to desist - I've seen people with a great deal of fraudulently obtained reputation have their score halved overnight once it was spotted.

Comment: So, this question will need some editing to make it on-topic. What does "doesn't work" mean? What debugging have you done? May we see your crash logs edited into the question? What did you learn from looking at the stack trace yourself?

Comment: To get your question answered you should make it as clear and helpful as you can. The first step is to clarify questions brought up in the comments by updating it.

Answer (score -1):

I understand that this question is not as per community guidelines, but come on, help a fellow programmer.

There is an issue with streaming in WebView as discussed in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=415344 so I think you are better off with Android's Media Player https://github.com/assen-totin/android-icecast-player/blob/master/src/com/voody/icecast/player/StationListenService.java

Kudos!